# Saving all the variables(Work Space) of a session in Python_Shelve_Pickle

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, workspace, shelve

I am trying to write a program in python, Which can work almost like a R's save. image which saves your  workspace. Follwoing is my code, but it is not running smoothly, Please help me to make it work

I have used following sample data and a plot so that it can be tested upon it

## Attempt1 -Using Shelve, dictionary Kind of  workspace saving

```
import shelve
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle
import os
import pandas as pd


x = np.arange(-3, 3, 0.01)
y = np.sin(np.pi*x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line=ax.plot(x, y)

#shelving or pickling my session

my_shelf = shelve.open('shelve.out','c') # 'n' for new
for name in dir():
    if not name.startswith (('__','_','In','Out','exit','quit','get_ipython')):
      try:
        my_shelf[name] = globals()[name] # I didn't undersatnd why to use globals()
      except Exception:
        pass
        print('ERROR shelving: {0}'.format(name))

my_shelf.close()
```

## To restore:

```
my_shelf = shelve.open('shelve.out','r')
for key in my_shelf:
    globals()[key]=my_shelf[key]

my_shelf.close()
```

## Trying One more attempt with Pickle this time:

```
 with open('save.p', 'wb') as f:
     for name in dir():
         if not name.startswith (('__','_','In','Out','exit','quit','get_ipython')):
             try:
               pickle.dump(name, f)
             except Exception:
               print('ERROR shelving: {0}'.format(name))
               pass


 with open('save.p',"rb") as f:  # Python 3: open(..., 'rb')
    pickle.load(f)
```

I Will highly appreciate any help, Apologies for any mis-indentation, while pasting on the overflow they got change

Answer (score 0):

The dill module provides this functionality.

dump_session(filename='/tmp/session.pkl', main=None, byref=False, **kwds)

load_session(filename='/tmp/session.pkl', main=None, **kwds)